# WCF service is failing for Operations returning Entity classes

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

My database is having following table

```
Country >> CountryId, Country
```

Following is the exact architecture in my application.

Geography_EF >> Entity framework project (using EF 5) 
Geography_Model >> Model generated from EF (in short, entity classes). This contains Country class. 
Geography_WCF >> WCF application containing various service contracts.

The issue is that when I write an operation contract returning Country object (or collection) it gives me an error saying "The underlying connection is closed. "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." Here, I can see the call gets completed to this operation contract and immediately this exception occurs.

whereas if I write an operation to return a specific field only (i.e. CountryId or Country table) then it works fine.

I am using repository pattern and Unity container as well.

What do you think, I am missing?

Comment: any idea of why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the size of the object. Check the MaxReceivedMessageSize in your config.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this error, I changed it from returning a collection to returning a List, and this solved the problem.  Hope it helps.